# Is google authentication method through firebase safe?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've used firebase authentication for my react app.But later many people said that firebase authentication is not much secure and they suggest me to go with JWT authentication or passport.js authentication methods.

But I don't want to shift from firebase because of its simpleness.Now I'm thinking to use google authentication signIn method in firebase. Is google authentication in firebase is also not safe? Is it safe to opt google authentication in firebase?

Comment: ask those guys what exactly is unsafe. I bet everyone saying that to you will have no clue how to break that authentification method. I think there are bug bounties (some of them around $10k-$50k) if you are able to find a bug in the authentication system

Comment: Firebase Authentication uses JWTs. Depending on the providers you use, it may also use OAuth2 (and even OAuth1 if you're using Twitter). But as others said: unless "many people" can post exactly what is "not much secure" about Firebase Authentication, it will be hard to dispel that myth.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing particularly "unsafe" about Firebase Authentication, especially compared to other options.  If another options meets your specific needs better, then go with it.  But without specific details on what you think to be unsafe about Firebase Auth, there is nothing really to say.